# Brightness get 0% at login screen

Tags: login, screen, brightness

I use Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. My laptop screen brightness get 0% at login screen after restart every time. When login screen first time appears the brightness level is ok but 1 second later goes to 0. I need to set it manualy to see password field.
Tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819320/screen-brightness-0-at-login-dims-at-boot) but it doesn't work.

You can check my inxi output about my hardwares [here.](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Zsf5bBYxZQ/)
HP Elitebook 845 G7

Can u help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

This phenomenon caused by Ambient light sensor.
If u have same problem just remove `iio-sensor-proxy` package with synaptic or via terminal.