# Ubuntu 20.04 - brightness of all apps get dimmed after login

Tags: 20.04, intel-graphics, screen, brightness

My issue is similar to [Screen Brightness 0% at login, dims at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819320/screen-brightness-0-at-login-dims-at-boot) except it is on desktop. Screen brightness is full on login prompt screen.

Next I hear a beep sound.

[Click here to listen beep](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/blob/master/sounds/src/stereo/bell.oga)

After login, all apps & background get dimmed except for the mouse cursor.

Playing a video in VLC automatically sets brightness to max.

Unfocusing from VLC player dims everything again.

This type of behavior should be observed in **laptops, not desktops**.

What I tried already:

- **gsettings** set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled false
- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux **acpi_backlight**=none"
- Disabled **power management** in both **Ubuntu & bios**
- **xrandr** brightness is already at 100%
- **Brightness Controller** app is already at 100%

I don't have a graphic card and use motherboard's chip to run my monitor.

This behavior is totally random. It either goes away itself or returns after few days/weeks. What am I missing here?

Screenshots: everything is dimmed.

[Screenshots (everything is dark)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlNcH.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Pastebin OS Info](https://pastebin.com/fxG9zAm5)

```
lsb_release -a give this info:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

hostnamectl gives this info:
   Static hostname: desktop-gigabyte
         Icon name: computer-desktop
           Chassis: desktop
        Machine ID: 991cfb62403b4b22ab380e98f552eeb6
           Boot ID: 51067401f74141c3a6e524778b013817
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.13.0-44-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

[Pastebin Internet & Hardware info](https://pastebin.com/iKN2G2yk)

```
desktop-gigabyte            
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: B365M DS3H (Default string)
    vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    version: Default string
    serial: Default string
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.1.1 dmi-3.1.1 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=Default string sku=Default string uuid=B4022E03-9904-CA05-BE06-340700080009
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: B365M DS3H
       vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       version: x.x
       serial: Default string
       slot: Default string
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: F5
          date: 08/13/2019
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 16MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 35
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 0
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2666 MHz (0.4 ns)
             vendor: Fujitsu
             physical id: 1
             serial: 39A40400
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
             size: 16GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 2
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
        *-bank:3
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 3
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 3b
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 384KiB
          capacity: 384KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 3c
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 1536KiB
          capacity: 1536KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 3d
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 9MiB
          capacity: 9MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9600K CPU @ 3.70GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 3e
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9600K CPU @ 3.70GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 4388MHz
          capacity: 4600MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities cpufreq
          configuration: cores=6 enabledcores=6 threads=6
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 0a
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop 9 Series)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:136 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-generic UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 8
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f722e000-f722efff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:132 memory:f7210000-f721ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.13.0-44-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.13
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=16 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Mouse
                   product: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
                   vendor: [Maxxter]
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Mouse
                   vendor: Racal Data Group
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: usb@1:2
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=202mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   product: CSR8510 A10
                   vendor: Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@1:5
                   version: 88.91
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:3
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard.
                   vendor: LITE-ON Technology
                   physical id: 8
                   bus info: usb@1:8
                   version: 1.09
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=70mA speed=2Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.13.0-44-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.13
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:135 memory:f722d000-f722dfff
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:134 memory:f7228000-f7229fff memory:f722c000-f722c0ff ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f722b000-f722b7ff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #19
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #20
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.3
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #21
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.4
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:125
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:126
        *-pci:5
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:127 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f7100000-f71fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
                logical name: enp6s0
                version: 16
                serial: b4:2e:99:ca:be:34
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.113 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:133 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7104000-f7104fff memory:f7100000-f7103fff
        *-pci:6
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:128
        *-pci:7
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #7
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.6
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:129 memory:f7000000-f70fffff
           *-network DISABLED
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
                vendor: Ralink corp.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
                logical name: wlp8s0
                version: 00
                serial: 48:02:2a:fb:83:18
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=5.13.0-44-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:18 memory:f7000000-f700ffff
        *-pci:8
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #8
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.7
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:130
        *-pci:9
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:131
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7224000-f7227fff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 200 Series PCH HD Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:137 memory:f7220000-f7223fff memory:f7200000-f720ffff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f722a000-f722a0ff ioport:f040(size=32)
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 1
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0400
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=parport_pc
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0501
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=serial
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          vendor: Interphase Corporation
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:08
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 9
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:09
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: a
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:0a
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: b
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: c
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: MTFDDAK128MAM-1J
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 070H
             serial: 1334094ACAF7
             size: 119GiB (128GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=24f25007
           *-volume
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 0fecaf25-a3e8-4966-bf2f-c0c49f6d9c9f
                size: 119GiB
                capacity: 119GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2020-08-23 14:21:08 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2023-01-05 09:44:46 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2023-01-05 09:44:46 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: d
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST2000VM003-1ET1
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: SC11
             serial: Z522BFMW
             size: 1863GiB (2TB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=5ae06f8f
           *-volume
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                logical name: /media/sule/Storage Disk
                version: 3.1
                serial: 1afd992e-142a-3347-a61d-12b8af257ab9
                size: 1863GiB
                capacity: 1863GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2018-07-12 20:21:11 filesystem=ntfs label=Storage Disk mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 state=mounted
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: e
          logical name: scsi5
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST2000VM003-1ET1
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdc
             version: SC11
             serial: W524P4X9
             size: 1863GiB (2TB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=373e59c6
           *-volume
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdc1
                logical name: /media/sule/Windows
                version: 3.1
                serial: 8cce88af-7346-104d-9269-64e5b67f6512
                size: 1863GiB
                capacity: 1863GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2020-02-12 08:58:45 filesystem=ntfs label=Windows mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 state=mounted
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       physical id: 1
       version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       capacity: 32768mWh
```

[Beep Noise](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/blob/master/sounds/src/stereo/bell.oga)

Comment: Have you tried different dekstop environments?

Comment: @ArjunKShibu Just checked different workspace. Didn't do anything. Brightness was consistent in both.

Comment: Not workspace, Are you currently running Wayland?

Comment: @ArjunKShibu No. I use Xorg/X11

Answer (score 0):

This can be set in three locations.

1. The SETTINGS menu, PRIVACY, SCREEN
2. The SETTINGS menu, POWER
3. BIOS

Also, if you are on battery and it runs low you may see it automatically go dim.  Make sure power cable is plugged in all the way.

Comment: I'm not on Laptop, therefore I have no battery. Settings screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/JIriTCa

What exactly do you recommend changing in Bios? I already set power management off in BIOS

Answer (score -1):

I also have this problem. I know of no workaround, however, if you simply click on the place where the slider is currently at, it seems to fix the problem. I believe this is a bug.

Comment: Only 2 ways I get my brightness back when I either open vlc media player or read a book using calibre. Either way it dims again if I switch to different app.